# I don't understand what the point is for having a config.py to hide my secret keys?

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I am attempting to deploy my flask application onto heroku. For my application, I have some constant variables and a secret key for WTForms in the repository. These values are stored in `config.py` in the route directory and my `app.py` file reads them from `app.config.from_object('config')` onto the application. Without these variables and values my app will of course break.

What I don't get it the point of moving something onto `config.py` is. I have to push this up to my repository for heroku to register the file but if I push it up to github then everyone will see my secret key. Am I supposed to place my config.py onto .gitignore?

-------------EDIT--------------

After reading the great resource on [Explore Flask](https://exploreflask.com/configuration.html) regarding Environment variable configurations, I'm afraid that I still don't get it. Let me elaborate.

My app absolutely refuses to work on Heroku and I suspect it is because of my `blackduck_directory/instance/config.py` file. This file is not being uploaded for some reason. Here is the error from the heroku logs:

`IOError: [Errno 2] Unable to load configuration file (No such file or directory): '/app/instance/config.py'`

Below that line is this:

```
at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=desolate-reaches-7133.herokuapp.com request_id=042226dc-5879-456a-8289-7c0f78c4e482 fwd="73.149.18.19" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=27430ms status=503 bytes=0
```

This is my app structure:

[image]

This is my blackduck_directory.py code that loads both `config.py`:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
app.config.from_pyfile('instance/config.py')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static/images')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # REMEMBER: Never have this set to True on Production
    # manager.run()
    app.run()
```

This is not technically correct but this works on both `localhost` and on `heroku local` but not in production.

I've tried to configure the blackduck_directory.py file like so:

Attempt #1

```
app = Flask(__name__, instance_path='/blackduck_directory/instance')
app.config.from_object('config')
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
```

Attempt #2:

```
app = Flask(__name__, instance_path='/instance')
app.config.from_object('config')
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
```

And all kins of combinations....... including `instance_relative_config=True`

I'm at my wits ends. I don't understand what the problem is. Do I have this wired wrong in my `blackduck_directory.py`? Is my tree structure wrong? What am I missing? I have the `/instance/config.py` file hidden on `.gitignore`. I understand its supposed to be hidden but if it's hidden on github how the hell is Heroku supposed to find it? So many questions........ Help please.

Comment: Put the secrets in another file, load the configuration, ignore that file.

Comment: Additionally, heroku has this link for environment variables https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars  This is very overwhelming, which is the right way?

Answer (score 3):

Robert Picard in his book [Explore Flask](https://exploreflask.com/index.html) suggests the following way of configuration.

Let's assume you have project with the following structure:

```
config.py
requirements.txt
run.py
instance/
  config.py
yourapp/
  __init__.py
  models.py
  views.py
  templates/
  static/
```

You place all the data that contains sensitive information (like API keys, passwords) in `instance/config.py` and exclude this directory from source control.

In order to load configuration variables from both files you can use the following code:

```
app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
app.config.from_object('config')
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
```

More information about configuration is in [corresponding book chapter](https://exploreflask.com/configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of separating secrets from the application code.  Putting them into a config.py file that is not part of the repository is one simple way of doing it, but it is far from the best way.  It is also kind of tedious because there are often other configurations that are not secrets and should be added to the source code.  Also if another developer pulls your code and tries to work with it in the development environment you want them to have all the necessary configurations.

What my company does is we have encrypt our passwords and certificates with a master password one for each environment, and check them in with all of our other configurations.  Then when it gets into production we pass the master password in as a system property in the command that starts the server or we put the master password somewhere on the file system of the server.

Comment: Adam, thanks for the reply but I still just don't get it. I keep trying to configure my heroku app and in the logs there is an error that looks like this

`IOError: [Errno 2] Unable to load configuration file (No such file or directory): '/app/instance/config.py' 

My app works on everything on `localhost` and on `heroku local` except for deployment! I hid the config file like the guide said so of course heroku wouldn't find the file. I just don't understand why it keeps crashing.

Comment: Heroku only uploads the files that are checked into git if I remember correctly.  Therefore your config file that you have you passwords in is not available to the app when it deploys.  You need to explicitly add it somehow or simply use the encryption approach I suggested.